# For remote hook, like post-receive, how to get the permission list for wildcard repository in gitolite?

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite

Working on the remote hook, **post-receive**, to send out notification emails by **post-receive-email**, and I am wondering if we can get the permission list just in **post-receive** for wildcard repositories instead of setting **hooks.mailinglist**?